# why will the following code not append one string to the other?

Tags: objective-c

it is the question from my friends. I have research some code from the internet but no help, i think it should working, the question is right.

```
NNString *s  = [[NNString alloc]initWithString:@"hello"];  
[s appendString:@"there"];
```

Comment: because you should read the documentation of the methods you use

Answer (score 1):

`NSString` is immutable, you'd need to use an instance of `NSMutableString` in order to be able to append to it.

```
NSMutableString *s  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];  
[s appendString:@"there"];
```

Alternatively you could replace the instance using `stringByApendingString:`.

Comment: so it is like "let" in SWIFT?

Comment: `let` creates a reference that can't be edited, but it could reference a mutable or immutable instance, what we're talking about here is the class and what interface it provides to you. So no, that's different.

Comment: Can I understand like that. NSString create a container that contain string type data. Once I place something into the container , the container can not be open anymore. If I want to change it , I can only replace the container, but I can not open the container and change the data.

Comment: And let actually create a address to the container, so it is different things

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to keep the string immutable:

```
s = [s stringByAppendingString:@" there"];
```